# Dropna with only one nan value in the df

Tags: pandas

I am searching and selecting values in a data frame in iteration and it happens that in a selection I may have only one row with a Nan value and I do not seem to be able to get rid of if. Used dropna and id didn't seem to do the trick.

`df2=df1.dropna(subset=['x'])`

I printed out other values and it looked like nan was removed for all except that case.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your DataFrame contains *NaN* in **other** column than *x*,
something like:

```
      x     y     z
0  10.0  20.0  30.0
1  11.0  22.0  33.0
2  40.5   NaN  80.4
3  60.5  80.2  90.4
```

Then `df1.dropna(subset=['x'])` is not likely to drop anything, because
*subset* narrows down the list of colums to search for *NaN* values.

If *NaN* can occur in **any** column, just drop *subset* parameter,
i.e. run `df2 = df1.dropna()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I review intentionally only one column and I want to remove the nan values only in it.

Comment: I checked your code against input containing a *NaN* in *x* column and the row containing it has been dropped. So your code is OK.

Comment: Cheers Valdi_Bo. I could not figure what was wrong with it. I already made a dirty workaround, where I convert the column to string and get rid of it consequently.